# How to build a high frequency digitally controlled variable gain amplifier

Tags: adc, dac

For a DDS I am working on, I need to build a variable gain amplifier with atleast 40-50db gain which can be controlled digitally. The bandwidth should be atleast 200MHz. Although I've seen some chips from LT and TI, they are too expensive and there aren't many covering this spec. I can of course come up with something using relays/passives and opamps, But I would like to know first if there are any recommended standard circuit's/practices.

Comment: Is this for a one-off, or for production?

Comment: Sounds hard. I'm not clear on what kind of answer you are expecting, though. Just general advice or a finished circuit or?

Comment: some general tips that are usually used.

Comment: Do you want a few coarse steps, say 10dB, which might be done with a video multiplexer and separate amplifiers, or finer steps where a variable gain amplifier would be better? You could consider an amplifier cascaded with an attenuator, or two such stages for better dynamic range control. You can get very good, value for money, wideband attenuators from the like of Peregrine. What's the low frequency end - DC - audio - 1 MHz, 50 MHz? That makes a difference too. How much of the variation can be supplied by generating a variable amplitude waveform from the DAC?

Comment: @Neil_UK It should start with DC. Steps should be fine - say atleast 200 levels. I'd like to keep the DAC at full scale all the time.

Comment: 200 levels over 50 dB range, so 1/4 dB steps. Last time I did something like that, I broke the range at about 3 MHz, much easier to handle both ranges separately than together.

Comment: @Neil_UK Are there any references that you can give for the type of circuits I can use as a starting point?

Comment: Just by chance I came across an amplifier in The Art of Electronics 3d edition. I think it was in chapter 5. It didn't exactly meet your specs, but it reminded me of your question. I can't really post the circuit, but I do suggest you pick up a copy of the book and look through it.

Comment: @mkeith I got the book will check it out. Thanks.